# state change not triggering a re-render

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I have a component call `ExpenseList.js` which does look like below. But my problem is when I tried to edit item and click save, setting `isEditable` inside "Save" button event handler does not trigger re-render.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useExpenses, useExpenseDispatch } from "./BudgetContext.js";

export default function ExpenseList() {
  const expenses = useExpenses();
  return (
    <ul>
      {expenses.map((expense) => (
        <li key={expense.id}>
          <Expense expense={expense} />
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

function Expense({ expense }) {
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useExpenseDispatch();
  let content;

  if (isEditing) {
    content = (
      <>
        <input
          value={expense.description}
          onChange={(e) => {
            dispatch({
              type: "changed",
              expense: {
                ...expense,
                description: e.target.value
              }
            });
          }}
        />
        <input
          value={expense.amount}
          onChange={(e) => {
            dispatch({
              type: "changed",
              expense: {
                ...expense,
                amount: e.target.value
              }
            });
          }}
        />
        <button onClick={() => setIsEditing(false)}>Save</button>
      </>
    );
  } else
    content = (
      <>
        <span>{expense.description}</span> : <span>{expense.amount}</span>
        <button onClick={() => setIsEditing(true)}>Edit</button>
      </>
    );

  return (
    <label>
      {content}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          dispatch({
            type: "deleted",
            id: expense.id
          });
        }}
      >
        Delete
      </button>
    </label>
  );
}
```

I was dabbling with this for hours, I think extra pair of eyes could point out what is going wrong?

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-keller-l5z42e?file=%2FExpenseList.js%3A0-1614

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example on stackblitz or codesandbox?

Comment: Not sure about the cause, but in general it's not a good idea to assign the elements to a variable in render. It will get recreated every render and all the state (if any) inside will get flushed. I would recommend a content component if you want to abstract this logic like <Content isEditing={isEditing} /> and put your logic in there or just put the logic in the return directly

Comment: @vighnesh153 added the sandbox link

Comment: I observed console logs, when you click Edit, `isEditing` becomes true. When you click Save, `isEditing` becomes `false`, then again `true`. Adding a `e.preventDefault()` to Save button fixed it like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-kate-i46xr2?file=/src/App.js:1179-1191 line $56

Comment: What I noticed is that when you change the `label` to `div`, it works.

Comment: I am not sure if having buttons inside of a label are a good idea (or how the event propagation works if we do add). Not able to find a good documentation reference to support. What you can try is just keeping the input fields wrapped in the label **(use different labels for different input fields)** and keep the buttons out of the label. Or if you don't have (or don't want to have) any accessibility text inside `label`, you can just replace the `label` with `div`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation reference](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element)

> Content model:
> Phrasing content, but with no descendant [labelable elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#category-label) unless it is the element's labeled control, and no descendant label elements.

As mentioned above, `label` has 2 different [labelable elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#category-label) unless it is the element's labeled control. When you are in edit mode, you have 3 different [labelable elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#category-label) (`input-description`, `input-amount` and `button-save`) which causes problems with event propagation.

But when you are **not** in edit mode, it just has 1 labelable element which is the `edit` button and hence, it works.

For solving your issue, you can swap the `label` at the root with something like `div` and then use labels explicitly for each of the `input`s in content.

```
function Expense({ expense }) {
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);  
  let content;

  if (isEditing) {
    content = (
      <>
        <label>
          Description: 
          <input
            value={expense.description}
            onChange={...}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Amount: 
          <input
            value={expense.amount}
            onChange={...}
          />
        </label>
        <button onClick={() => setIsEditing(false)}>Save</button>
      </>
    );
  } else
    content = (
      <>
        <button onClick={() => setIsEditing(true)}>Edit</button>
      </>
    );

  return (
    <div>
      {content}
      <button>Delete</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```